# SQL queries with PHP and smarty templates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, smarty

I'm trying to display the results from a SQL query on my results.tpl page.

I've been banging my head against this all day, can someone look at my code and point me in the right direction?  Or am I better off trying to do some sort of javascript/ajax to get this working?

For context, I'm using booked scheduler.  In order for the page to match the site template - I have to link to results.php which goes to resultspage.php which goes to results.tpl.  But I can't put results.php in the smarty->display.

Basically here's the flow of what I'm trying to do.  There are a lot more queries/results I need to add but I'm just trying to get the basics working...

scan.tpl user enters number -> handler.php queries database -> results.tpl display results

Any help is much appreciated!

**scan.tpl**

```
{include file='globalheader.tpl'}
<div id="xx">
<form action="handler.php" method="post" >
<input type="number" name="barcode" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form >
</div>
{include file='globalfooter.tpl'}
```

**handler.php**

```
{require_once('c:/xxx/Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$host = "xxx";
$user = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$database_name = "xxx";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$search=$_POST['barcode'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxx LIKE '$search' LIMIT 0 ,   10");
$query->bindValue(1, "$search", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

$results = $query->fetch();

$smarty->assign('output', '$results');
$smarty->display('results.tpl')
```

**results.tpl**

```
{include file='globalheader.tpl'}
<div id="xx">
{$output}
</div>
{include file='globalfooter.tpl'}
```

Comment: remove the `'` (single quotes) on the `$results` `$smarty->assign('output', $results);`.  Then on your **results.tpl** you should do a `loop` on your `$output`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I removed the single quotes from the $results.  Not sure why I still had those there

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your  handler.php has some errors. At first, you have to start the php file with `<?php`. Second, string substitution only works in double quoted strings - but if you don't need substitution, just use the var.

```
<?php
require_once('c:/xxx/Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$host = "xxx";
$user = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$database_name = "xxx";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$search=$_POST['barcode'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxx LIKE '$search' LIMIT 0 ,   10");
$query->bindValue(1, $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$smarty->assign('output', $results);
$smarty->display('results.tpl')
```

also you should use some kind of loop in your output.tpl  file to display the result.

```
{include file='globalheader.tpl'}
<div id="xx">
<ul>
{foreach from=$output item="item"}
    <li>{$item.xxx}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
</div>
{include file='globalfooter.tpl'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  After submitting the form I'm getting Fatal error: Uncaught--> Unable to load template file 'results.tpl'

Comment: The results.tpl file have to be in your template directory - if you don't change `$smarty->template_dir` with `$smarty->setTemplateDir`, this sould be `templates`

Comment: I've got it in the same directory as all the other .tpl files.  /tpl also in /lang

Comment: Let me take another look and I'll give that a try.  Appreciate the help

Comment: If the template file is inside `tpl`, you have to call `$smarty->setTemplateDir('./tpl')`

Comment: I've added the line but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: I can view results.tpl by manually going to results.php - however adding the {$output} causes the page to show an unknown error despite the template displaying correctly

Comment: You should use `$pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead of `$pdo->fetch()` and use a foreach loop (like in my answer) to output the result.